# Problems with running Python in Virtual environments after Python update

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-venv, virtual-environment

I used Python 3.7 for many Django projects using virtual environments (venv) under Windows. The Python path was

```
C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
```

now I upgrated python to 3.9 and the current path is

```
C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
```

Now when I want to run Python in any of my past projects, for example

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get the error
No Python at 'C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe'

Which is quite normal.

How could I update each project in order to accept the new path? Is there a way to do this or should I better downgrade to Python 3.7 and use it forever? Renaming the folder where Python is installed doesn't seem a good idea. It must surely be a configuration file to change, a variable to set or whatever. I'm relatively new with Python and I never faced this problem before.

Could you help?

Comment: Try changing your Python Path environment variable to the new path.

Comment: The path in windows is already updated since I made a fresh install of the new version of Python (and I verified). If you mean another path inside the virtual environment, I don't know where it is located.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pycharm, try changing the path of base interpreter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on command prompt set the PATH set PATH=C:\Program Files\Python39;%PATH%

Comment: The PATH environment variable already exists as I explained in the comments. But it seems that there is not solution using venv. The best solution I found is to get the installed packages using pip freeze > requirements.txt (after I temporarly rename the python directory) and then I create a new virtual environment taking the requirements into account. Including the version number in the Python directory name is indeed a very poor decision and it doesn't make sense at all.